# How can i solve foreign key no index parent?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, popsql

i only started learning SQL myself for the past 2 days and now i encounter a problem with linking column on different table using foreign key constraint.
Below is my code.

```
    CREATE TABLE analytics (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    status BOOLEAN,
    server_id INT,  /* link with server info*/     
    source_id INT,      /*link with input source*/
    ext VARCHAR(5),
    startframe_id_x INT,
    endframe_id_x INT,
    mask VARCHAR(20),
    label VARCHAR(20),
    countline INT,
    det_deviceid INT,
    processing_period TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (server_id) REFERENCES server_info(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES input_source(id)
);


CREATE TABLE statistics (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    source_id INT,  /*link with input source*/
    analytic_id INT, /*link with analytic*/
    time_recorded TIMESTAMP,
    duration TIME,   /*link with analytics processing period*/
    counter INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES input_source(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (analytic_id) REFERENCES analytics(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (duration) REFERENCES analytics(processing_period)
);
```

the problem occurs on this line

```
   FOREIGN KEY (duration) REFERENCES analytics(processing_period)
```

which i am not sure and used up countless of hours searching and figuring out solutions but still can't fix it.

It gave out error like this `"ER_FK_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'statistics_ibfk_3' in the referenced table 'analytics'"`

anyone could give out any idea why this problem occurs? im using Popsql to edit my code and use the mysql database.

Would appreciate some explanation or solution.

Comment: The error is on  FOREIGN KEY (duration) REFERENCES analytics(processing_period) and is because there is no index on processing_period.

Comment: is there any way to solve this? @P.Salmon

Comment: 'there is no index on processing_period' - way to solve this is to add an index - if you cannot do that then you cannot have an FK on it and you may have to use a trigger to validate duration.

Comment: The column which FOREIGN KEY refers on (analytics.processing_period) must be defined as UNIQUE by according index.

Comment: @Akina from my understanding, i need to change the analytics.processing_period to unique data type? is it correct?

Comment: Yes. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON analytics (processing_period);`. But you must ensure that the column values are unique - if not then index creation will fail.

Comment: InnoDB does NOT require the referenced index to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE statistics (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    source_id INT,  /*link with input source*/
    analytic_id INT, /*link with analytic*/
    time_recorded TIMESTAMP,
    counter INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES input_source(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (analytic_id) REFERENCES analytics(id)
);
```

Note that `duration` has been removed.  If you want the processing period, then use `JOIN` to match to the `analytics` table.